# Is requesting a planned date for some future event offtopic?

Tags: discussion

I don't understand why [When is CPython moving to Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120187/when-is-cpython-moving-to-mercurial-closed) was closed as off-topic. Would have been nice if there was some explanation on the Comments. Can someone explain here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I voted to close because the question wasn't related to programming in the sense that you weren't asking a question about *how to do something directly related to programming*.  Looking at the FAQ, we see that acceptable questions are:

1. a specific programming problem
2. a software algorithm
3. software tools commonly used by programmers
4. matters that are unique to the programming profession

Which bullet point do you think it fits under? Arguably three but I would say that it's far too specific. One of the options that comes up on the vote to close dialogue is:

> **too localized**
>   This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

I might have actually voted to close it for that reason, although I'm not sure. It only displays the most voted reason which is off-topic. If I could go back in time and vote to close as too localized, I probably would (but only if I could look at a winning lottery number first, it's really not that big a deal)

You might also make an argument that it fits into point four, but It's *still* too localized and I personally think that point four is made weaker now that the programmers site is up and running. If it was up to me, I'd move it down into the "dont ask here" part of the FAQ with a reference to [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). I haven't hung out long enough to know if your question would have been appropriate there but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there was some:

> Tshepang: Is it possible to answer this question here with any objectivity? – pyfunc 8 hours ago
>
> Voting to close; question asks to predict the future. – Greg Hewgill 8 hours ago

Comment: I responded to that. It turned out that she didn't really understand my question.

Comment: @Tsh Well, close votes aren't retractable, so even if you countered every argument made, that was why they voted to close

Comment: not good. Sure these guys are heroic, but this approach is simply not acceptable. I'm not arguing that I'm right, but I'm simply arguing that they didn't really justify why the Question was offtopic.